# What happens when you cook tree spinach with aluminum?

Tags: biochemistry, botany, food, toxicology

The Internet is [filled with warnings](https://www.drweil.com/diet-nutrition/cooking-cookware/cooking-chaya/) that you shouldn't cook [tree spinach(*Cnidoscolus aconitifolius*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cnidoscolus_aconitifolius) in aluminum, because it will react and create toxins that cause explosive diarrhea when consumed. However, I can't find anything more specific than that. Does something (presumably hydrocyanic acid(HCN)) from tree spinach react with aluminum? If so, how does the resulting product cause diarrhea?

Comment: If aluminium is present in a hot medium wtih cyanide, perhaps it can produce aluminium cyanide?   i had a look at aluminium use as a catalyst in organic chemistry, it could be anything, there is however something called...Cyanosilylation: Aluminum alkoxides, such as aluminum isopropoxide (Al(O-i-Pr)3), are employed as catalysts in cyanosilylation reactions, which involve the addition of a cyano group to a carbonyl compound plus another group.